# Insert a variable inside Formula

Tags: excel, vba

I have a cell in that contains the following:

```
=$H$10+1&","&B5+I10&","&(2*$D$2+$E$2)/2
```

The result of this formula is in this format:

```
14649,28.25,5.5
```

[image]

I want to use the formula VBA code. I want the number `1` in the `$H$10+**1**&"` to be the i of the for loop and the `I10` in `"&B5+I10&"` to also change with the loop.

```
For i=1 to lastrow
.Range("X" & 13+i & "").Formula = "=$H$10+" & i & "" & "," & "B5+I" & i + 10 & "" & "," & "(2*$D$2+$E$2)/2"
Next i
```

Comment: Put spaces around all the `&`s.

Comment: Please post the complete code and what error do you get

Comment: Actually it's kind of confusing what you want, It would help you to obtain an adequate answer, if you please show us a screenshot of the actual values and the expected outcome. Bear in mind that your code just updates cell `X14` as many time as the value of `lastrow` but you would only be able to see the last update. Therefore, I suggest that you better explain clearly what you want to achieve.

Comment: Thank you for your repley@RicardoDiaz the error is run time error '1004'

Comment: Thank you for your reply @EEM, you are right about the X14 I have edited it and added a screenshot.

Comment: Actually it should be something like `For i =X to lastrow`, where `X` is the first row?

Comment: Do you need VBA for this, why not just copy the formula downwards?…

Comment: Yes, I actually did not use the for loop yet, I only try to get the formula right. It is not only for one column. I also need it for other columns. Also, the number of rows is variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here code that can be used:

```
Sub mySub()
    '=$H$10+1&","&B5+I10&","&(2*$D$2+$E$2)/2
    Dim myRange As Range
    Set myRange = Range("H:H").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell)
    Dim myStr As String
    'A=10 is for assigning first row in H as your data, hope no data upward from row 9 to row 1

    For Baris = 10 To myRange.Row
        On Error Resume Next
        myStr = "=$H$10+" & Baris - 9 & "&"",""&B5+I" & Baris & "&"",""&(2*$D$2+$E$2)/2"
        Range("K" & Baris).Formula = myStr

    Next
End Sub
```